# VS2008 Start Page replacement

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I really don't like the VS2008 Start Page. I don't need the RSS reader, Getting started or Headlines. The only thing useful is "Recent Projects"

**Is there a way to customize it or replace with a better one?**
It will be nice that the page contains Favorites Projects and Recent projects.

P.S. I know that I can disabled it or replace it with other web page, just looking for a good productivity tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an article with a lot of detail on how to precisely customize the start page.  Unfortunately, it looks to be a rather arduous process.  But hey, if you have the time...

[Customizing the Visual Studio .NET 2003 Start Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290348.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Goto Tools > Options > Environment > Startup and pick the best option you like

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be to follow the steps here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2008/01/03/did-you-know-how-to-customize-what-visual-studio-opens-to-or-how-to-make-the-start-page-not-show-up-when-vs-opens.aspx

You can also check out the useful information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa991992.aspx).  Aso for suggested things, check out this [post](http://www.bluevisionsoftware.com/WebSite/TipsAndTricksDetails.aspx?Name=VSStartPage).

Comment: Good links, not so useful. In a side note: did you see the steps required to remove a project in the "Recent projects" list? Ridiculous

Answer (score 0):

The link posted by Kyralessa is a complete answer to your original question.  Unfortunately, it does look like a complicated procedure.

I'll just add that if you're worried about any performance impact associated with fetching the RSS feed, you can enter a non-existent URL such as `http://localhost:12345` that will fail quickly and reduce the amount of content needing to be rendered.  In that way, you could keep the 'Recent projects' panel.

Answer (score 0):

I too am not a fan of the startup page showing latest articles and news from MSDN.

I wouldn't mind glancing through a few articles, but the RSS feed is mega slow and the wait really slows down productivity, especially if I find myself opening and close it all the time.

Visual Studio will load much faster when the start page is disabled.

Here's how to do it:

> Go to **Tools** => **Options**
>
> Select the **Startup** child node under the **Environment** node.
>
> **Un-tick** the auto loading of news articles
>
> Clear the **url box** ...just to be sure ;)
>
> Select **"Show empty environment"** from the combo box

Now, marvel at the dramatic speed boost to Visual studio 2008.